# LIBGDX creating a main menu

Tags: java, libgdx

So i want to create a mainmenu for my game and i'm stuck on what to do next i have all the art done and it's all in layers and packed in a .pack

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen {

CrazyZombies game;
Stage stage;
BitmapFont font;
TextureAtlas MainMenu;
Texture road;
Skin skin;
SpriteBatch batch;

public MainMenu(CrazyZombies game){
    this.game = game;
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.09f, 0.28f, 0.2f, 1);

    stage.act(delta);

    batch.begin();
    stage.draw();
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    if(stage == null)
        stage = new Stage(width, height, true);
    stage.clear();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

}

@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    skin = new Skin();
    MainMenu = new TextureAtlas("data/mainmenu/MainMenu.pack");

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
    MainMenu.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
}
}
```

If anyone could give me some guidelines or tutorials on what to do now it would be great i've looked in a lot of places but they have not given me the required answers.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this tutorial which sums up what you want exactly:

[LibGDX: Using a Splash Screen or Menu](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/UsingASplashScreen)

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? This link explains absolutely everything you need to create a menu screen.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to

1. create a skin, and
2. we need to add buttionTextureStyle to it.
3. Don't forget to add fonts, it took me a hour to figure out that fonts are not set by default like other parameters of buttonTextureStyle
4. and then you create a button with created skin
5. and then add that button to the stage.

Answer (score 1):

i think it will be easy if u use scene2D that will handle all the complexity and help you to create a nice looking UI with a little bit of code .

you may need to check this link 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui