# LibGdx - How to create a Screen for Game-Preferences? Example?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

I am new in the "LibGdx - game development" topic and try to implement a small game.
I would like first to start with a "preferences"-screen, similar like:

https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/perfdone.png

or like:

https://img.degreed.com/image/fetch/pg_1/w_564,h_175,c_fill,g_faces:center,f_auto,q_auto,dpr_2.0/http%3A%2F%2F4.bp.blogspot.com%2F-0704s6KBqxk%2FT1gak1cbNVI%2FAAAAAAAAA-4%2F5T0dgHWBYfA%2Fs400%2FOptionsScreen.png

I was also searching in google, but those examples does not help for me as a starter with less knowledge.

I would be happy, if someone could help me with that.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LIBGDX creating a main menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529869/libgdx-creating-a-main-menu)

Comment: Thanks, it helps a bit, but does not answear my question, because some links of the question does not work, or are outdated